# nvalid Number query error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Oracle query which uses two subqueries to get the number of items for a specific date.

```
 SELECT to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY') expiration_date
                            ,(SELECT SUM(u.base_quantity)
                                FROM unit u
                                    ,item i
                               WHERE i.item_id = u.item_id
                                 AND (i.item_code = 50002844 OR
                                     i.item_id = 50002844)
                                 AND to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY') =
                                    count_units.expiration_date) AS quantity
                            ,count_units.unit_count
                            ,count_available_units.available_unit_count
                        FROM unit u
                            ,(SELECT to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS expiration_date
                                    ,COUNT(*) AS unit_count
                                FROM unit u
                                    ,item i
                               WHERE (u.item_id = 50002844 OR
                                     i.item_code = 50002844)
                                 AND u.item_id = i.item_id
                                 AND u.base_quantity > 0
                               GROUP BY to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')) count_units
                            ,(SELECT to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS expiration_date
                                    ,COUNT(*) AS available_unit_count
                                FROM unit u
                                    ,item i
                               WHERE (u.item_id = 50002844 OR
                                     i.item_code = 50002844)
                                 AND u.item_id = i.item_id
                                 AND u.status_id = 10
                                 AND u.base_quantity > 0
                               GROUP BY to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')) count_available_units
                         WHERE count_units.expiration_date = to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')
                         AND count_available_units.expiration_date = to_char(u.expiration_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

the two subqueries here are count_units and count_available_units. It's important that I group by to_char([date],[date format]) because otherwise it will group by the date and time rather than just the date. when I was grouping by just `u.expiration_date` the query returned results but now upon running this I receive "invalid number" error.

My question is why am I getting this error? I don't see any place in my query where it would be attempting to convert a char to a number or vice versa.

Also, the two subqueries on their own return without error, so it must be some criteria that I'm querying on.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Tip: Comment out  until it works debug technique, then introduce line by line.

Comment: Found it. it was trying to conver my row_number rn to number I think? I changed it to to_date instead of to_char and it's working. Thanks